# Alembic: is there a way to store head revision number in DB?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

Is there any way to store current revision number in the db? I mean, when I generate migration and upgrade head, how I can insert this revision number in the db, and check the table for this revision number in next time, when I will do a migration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current HEAD is automatically stored in the `version_number` column in the `alembic_version` table in your database.  You can retrieve it with this query:

```
SELECT version_num FROM alembic_version;
```